# Click an HTML link inside a WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, browser, hyperlink

C#  Visual Studio 2010

I am loading a complex html page into a webbrowser control.  But, I don't have the ability to modify the webpage.  I want to click a link on the page automatically from the windows form.  But, the ID appears to be randomly generated each time the page is loaded (so I believe referencing the ID will not work).

This is the content of the a href link:

```
<a
```

`id="u_lp_id_58547" 
href="javascript:void(0)" 
class="SGLeftPanelText" onclick="setStoreParams('cases;212', 212); window.leftpanel.onClick('cases_ss_733');return false; ">`

```
My Assigned</a>
```

Is the anyway to click the link from C#?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

I feel like this is close but it is just not working:

```
HtmlElementCollection links = helpdeskWebBrowser.Document.Window.Frames["main_pending_events_frame"].Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
MessageBox.Show(links.Count.ToString());
```

I have tried plugging in every single frame name and tried both "a" and "A" in the TagName field but just have not had any luck.  I can just not find any links; the message box is always 0.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
HtmlElement link = webBrowser.Document.GetElementByID("u_lp_id_58547")
link.InvokeMember("Click")
```

EDIT:

Since the IDs are generated randomly, another option may be to identify the links by their `InnerText`; along these lines.

```
HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");

foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.InnerText.Equals("My Assigned"))
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can get the links within an IFrame using:

```
webBrowser.Document.Window.Frames["MyIFrame"].Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
```

Comment: but the question says "But, the ID appears to be randomly generated each time the page is loaded (so I believe referencing the ID will not work)."

Comment: John, you are correct -- the links get a random number assigned to them each time you open the page.  This method is what I keep coming across in my searches but I can't figure out another way to implement it without using the ID.

The 'cases_ss_733' is always the same, I just don't know how that could be used.

Comment: @John. Yes you're right, but the randomly generated id portion was added after my initial response. 

@Josh. Could you identify the link by the InnerText value?

Comment: I believe that has me really close Garett! Thank you for following up.  I tested it and I did not work but I believe that's because the My Assigned link is buried within an iFrame. 



I tried inserting a MessageBox.Show(link.InnerText) above the if statement and nothing came up.  So then I did a View Source on the frameset page and ran a find for <a and nothing came up.  

So that makes sense but now the question is, can I get to the link that's embedded in an iFrame.  (and thank you so much for the help!)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!  I finally figured out it was buried under and additional frame.  Once I got drilled down into the second level of frames I found the My Assigned link.  Thanks again Garett!

Comment: Useful thanks very much. Had to change .GetElementByID to .GetElementById

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will have to isolate the link ID value using more of the surrounding HTML context as a "target" and then extract the new random ID.

In the past I have used the "[HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)" to easily parse "screen-scraped" HTML to isolate areas of interest within a page - this library seems to be easy to use and reliable.