# How to invoke click on a link in the web browser?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, click

Okay lets say the page contains a link called 'About Us'. Instead of me doing:

```
webBrowser.Navigate ("www.page.com/aboutus");
```

...how can I tell my program to click any link that contains the text About Us?

I know this might seem like Im doing more work then necessary I have too but trust me I need this bit of code.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479490/click-an-html-link-inside-a-webbrowser-control

Hope that helps...

Comment: How is this question different than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300215/how-to-click-emails-with-html-agility-pack and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295871/c-how-to-invoke-a-click-in-a-httpwebrequest and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299848/c-how-to-click-emails-in-web-browser?

Comment: @PaulWalls There different because the other I asked involving httpwebrequest and HTML agility pack, this one is with the browser :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the `HtmlElement` object for the `<a>` tag, then call `InvokeMember("click")`.

If the element has an ID, you can get it by calling `Document.GetElementById`; otherwise, you can look through `GetElementsByTagName` and find the element you're looking for.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code using the example in my initial thread please?

Comment: You need to figure out how to find the `HtmlElement` for the `<a>` tag.  This will depend on what the page looks like.  Firebug will be very useful.

Comment: This is what Im working with but nothing is being clicked:      HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");

foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.InnerText.Equals("Confirm your account," +  textBox1.Text))
        link.InvokeMember("Click");



}

Comment: @Edwin: Use the debugger to find out what the `Text` is and adjust your condition to match.

Comment: I told my code to search for exactly what Firebug told me the text was but I keep getting: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Use the debugger to find the problem.

Comment: Debugger? Im sorry but Im new to Firebug

Comment: No.  Use the Visual Studio debugger to find out why your condition isn't firing or to find out what's null.

Comment: How would I use the debugger? I added a breakpoint and I was stepping into it but dont see how that will help me find out why I got the error?

Comment: Something is null.  You need to figure out what is null.