# How can I click a js button on VB

Tags: javascript, button, click

i am using visual basic 12.there is a web browser in my form.İ want to click it but i have a problem.The button is a javascript button.so this code doesn't work:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.All("button id").InvokeMember("click")
```

Here is the hmtl of button.How can i click it.

```
<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin_407311();">
                                        <span>&nbsp;</span><div class="btn3">Like</div></a>
```

Comment: What control are you using to display the web browser... web browser control/component?

Comment: I've added a possible answer to your question...

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

1. Execute the javascript function itself directly
2. Search through all A elements using InnerHTML
3. Search through all A elements using ClassName

### Execute the javascript function itself directly

*Edit:* Thanks to pquest for pointing out you can execute the javascript function directly with:

```
Browser.InvokeScript("openFbLWin_407311");
```

More complicated (and not really necessary) :

```
WbBrowser.Navigate( new Uri("javascript:(function(){ openFbLWin_407311(); })();") )
```

---

### Search through all A elements using InnerHTML

Have a look at the following question: [Click an HTML link inside a WebBrowser Control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3479490/1688441)

In your case, based on that link, something like this:

```
Dim links As HtmlElementCollection
links = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")

For Each link As HtmlElement In links
   If link.InnerHtml.IndexOf("Like") <> -1 Then
            link.InvokeMember("Click")
   End If
Next
```

---

### Search through all A elements using ClassName

```
 If link.GetAttribute("className") = "single_like_button btn3-wrap" Then
    link.InvokeMember("Click")
 End If
```

---

### All Three Methods:

**VB.net**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Url = New Uri("file:///D:/clickJSbutton.html")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Method 1: Execute javascript directly
         Browser.InvokeScript("openFbLWin_407311");
         'WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri("javascript:(function(){ openFbLWin_407311(); })();"))

        'Method 2: Find the link from all links
        Dim links As HtmlElementCollection
        links = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")

        For Each link As HtmlElement In links
            'Method 2B: Using some kind of inner html
            If link.InnerHtml.IndexOf("Like") <> -1 Then
                link.InvokeMember("Click")
            End If

            'Method 2C: Using className as identifier
            If link.GetAttribute("className") = "single_like_button btn3-wrap" Then
                link.InvokeMember("Click")
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you are using the WPF Browser Control, you can also call `Browser.InvokeScript("openFbLWin_407311");`