# Button clicking blues (click js button from vbs)

Tags: javascript, vbscript, frame

Just when I thought I could handle any button, I come across one that is responding to NOTHING I try.  Here is the basic frame of my code (very basic).  Just trying to open this page and click the next page button.

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://centraloklahomaproperties.com/SiteContent/OKC/MemberSearchOKC.aspx"
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 100: Loop

On error resume next

Dim i
i = 0

Do while i < 5
i = i + 1

Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 100: Loop

'Click button here!

Loop
```

Things I've tried:

```
1) IE.Navigate "javascript:open.document.getElementByID('btnRight').onclick;"

2) IE.Navigate "Javascript:window.opener.btnright.click();"

3) For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
If btn.id = "btnRight" Then btn.Click()
Next

4) ie.navigate "javascript:InvokeScript('Next(1)');"

5) Browser.InvokeScript("Next(1)")

6) ie.Navigate( Uri("javascript:(function(){ Next(1); })();") )

7) Set oButton = IE.getElementById("btnRight")
oButton.Click()
```

Also tried methods here:
[How can I click a js button on VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656344/how-can-i-click-a-js-button-on-vb)

Here is button html:

```
<img width="30" height="28" id="btnRight" onmouseover="Tab(event)" onmouseout="Tab(event)" onclick="Next(1);" alt="Next" src="http://centraloklahomaproperties.com/SiteContent/OKC/images/icon_arrow_next-default.gif">
```

What's weird is, unless I specifically right click the left frame and view source, it's as if that frame doesn't even exist.  If I just open the page in IE and go to >Edit>Source, it's non existent.  Might be part of my problem.

Comment: An image isn't a button, however you can invoke the onclick handler with `onclick()`.

Comment: This sounds promising - what's the correct syntax?  I'm wondering if I need some method to target the left frame?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
```

to

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application","objIE_")
```

How about:

```
Set oButton = IE.getElementById("btnRight")
oButton.Click()
```

Comment: Remove the on error resume next and paste the error if there is one.

Comment: Line 17 / Char 1: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'IE.getElementById'

Comment: Looks like the source contains iframes - does that change the way I should approach it?    <iframe id="Menu" name="Menu" src="../MemberList.aspx" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<iframe id="Content" name="Content" src="../MemberDetail.aspx"  scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: Tried Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application","objIE_"), and same error.  Did the solution you proposed work for you?

Comment: I just tried. It is because of the iFrames. I loaded the page, puked it to a text file, ctrl+f for "btnRight" and it's not in there. I'm not sure there is a good solution to this. I'll try a few things.

Comment: So, it's not just me!  I appreciate it, Nathan.

Comment: Any success with this?

Comment: I spent about an hour trying various methods and I couldn't get it to work unfortunately.