# Click on button in jquery with VBA

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, button, jqgrid

For numerous days I have been looking for a way to enter a site to retrieve data automatically. I have been able to login on the site and click on the requested tabs on a certain page. The final step I need to do is to click on the button "Clear" on that page. So far I have tried:

```
For Each aInput In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("hoofdleidingGrid")
    If aInput.getAttribute("value") = "Clear" Then
        aInput.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next aInput
```

and

```
tekst = "<span class=" & Chr(34) & "ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" & Chr(34) & "></span>"
Set elementcol = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each link In elementcol
    Debug.Print link.innerHTML
    If link.innerHTML = tekst Then
        link.Focus
        link.Click
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)

    End If
Next link
```

In both codes the line with .Click executes but there is no result like when it is done manually. 
The section of the code on the website which contains the buttons is:

```
> jQuery('#hoofdleidingGrid').jqGrid('navGrid',"#hoofdleidingPaginatie",
> {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false}); 
> jQuery('#hoofdleidingGrid').jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#hoofdleidingPaginatie",
> {caption:"Clear",title:"Clear Search",buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh', 
> onClickButton:function(){jQuery('#hoofdleidingGrid')[0].clearToolbar(); }}); 
> jQuery('#hoofdleidingGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult:true, 
> searchOnEnter: true});});</script><table id="hoofdleidingGrid"><tr><td /></tr>
> </table><div id="hoofdleidingPaginatie"></div>        
> <script type="text/javascript">
```

I hope somebody can help me out.
Many thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Roncancio

Comment: Look answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656344/how-can-i-click-a-js-button-on-vb

Comment: Something like this? `IE.document.parentWindow.execscript "$('#hoofdleidingGrid').click()"`

Comment: @parik. Sorry for the late response. Many thanks for your reply. When I add the code link.InvokeMember ("Click") to the code I receive the error message: "Error 438 object doesn't support this property or method access"

Comment: @ryan. Sorry for the late response. Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately like with my code the button doesn't respond. I have added the wait command so the code will execute when the web page is loaded but to no avail.

Comment: Is it possible to share the website in question? At this point, it might be more helpful to see it in action.

Comment: You are right but I am sorry. It is classified information for which you have to login. When entering the page there is already a filter that hides all the data. By clicking on the Clear button any filter on the page will be removed. I am currently in contact with the manufacturer of the program to automatically load the page without any filter. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: As promised I keep you informed. I have contacted the company who made the program and they will adjust the program so the filter automatically gets  cleared when loading the page. They advised me to update my Windows version (now 9).