# How to click Webbrowser list row

Tags: vb.net, list, click, browser

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTjVO.jpg

```
wb.Document.All("stable-mainTorList-row-FCB95F2DACC8C47B2E671634FEE83ECBBD724C7A").InvokeMember("click")

wb.Document.All("stable-mainTorList-row-FCB95F2DACC8C47B2E671634FEE83ECBBD724C7A").RaiseEvent("onClick")

wb.Document.All("stable-mainTorList-row-FCB95F2DACC8C47B2E671634FEE83ECBBD724C7A").SetAttribute("classname", "selected")
```

These codes not working.

How to click these rows? What are the other alternatives? Does it work use javascript?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click an HTML link inside a WebBrowser Control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479490/click-an-html-link-inside-a-webbrowser-control)

Comment: I reviewed this post. But I did not get a answer.