# Auto click option value using webbrowser in c#

Tags: c#, browser

I have code Html as following:

```
<select name="film_episode">
  <option value="1111">Post 1</option>
  <option value="2222">Post 2</option>
  <option value="3333">Post 3</option>
</select>
```

how to use 'webbrowser' in c# click on selected automatically 'Post 2'.

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479490/click-an-html-link-inside-a-webbrowser-control

Comment: Why don't you use a `runat=server` to make things easier

Comment: go through the answer that i have posted you will understand easily

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get things easier

```
<select runat="server" id="dropDownList1" name="film_episode">
  <option value="1111">Post 1</option>
  <option value="2222">Post 2</option>
  <option value="3333">Post 3</option>
</select>
```

in Code behind(aspx.cs)

```
dropDownList1.Items.FindByText("Post 2").Selected = true;
```